# Unable to pull up a field value in Drupal 7. Is this a bug?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

Global $user;

```
$items = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_patientid', $user->language);
```

I have a field on user entity and I always get a value of FALSE in my debug.

In my database I have the correct entity type which is user. Why am I not getting any values?

I am able to pull up value using:

```
$user_fields->field_patientid['und']['0']['value'];
```

Why will the above mentioned statement not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code for [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), you'll notice that the field information you're looking for needs to already be in the `$user` object in order for it to be returned by the function.

But `global $user` does not provide the field data.

From http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/user/7#comment-13744

> The global user object contains some basic data from Drupal core. It
>   does not automatically include data from other modules, including the
>   core profile module. To get all data in the user object, you need to
>   do a full [user_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7).